# How do I include "x64" in path name when starting powershell with a CD command?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to automatically change the directory when powershell starts from an application which provides the location to change to.

It works for most of the paths but when I have a path with "(x64)" (I imagine that "(x86)" would behave in the same way) it fails with this error message:

[First error](https://imgur.com/blNjFtL)

```
# Using the -NoExit just to see if the code works correctly,
# will be removed when it does.

powershell -NoExit "CD ""D:\My (x64) path"""
```

I have tried changing it in different ways but always get the same error. Here is what I have tried (or at least all methods I can remember I've tried):

```
1. powershell -NoExit "CD `"D:\My (x64) path`""

2. powershell -NoExit "CD D:\My (x64) path"

3. powershell -NoExit "CD `"D:\My `(x64`) path`""
```

If I instead use:

```
powershell -NoExit "CD ""D:\My ('x64') path"""
```

or:

```
powershell -NoExit "CD ""D:\My '(x64)' path"""
```

The error I get changes to this:

[Second error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fti1q.jpg)

All changes made in the path (D:\My (x64) path) as seen in the three latest examples are also impractical since the path is provided by another application and I don't know what it is in advanced (which means I would have to write a much longer code to search for those occasions in the path).

Hope you understand my problem and that you can help me, otherwise just ask and I will try to explain it more.

Comment: did you test `set-location` like `set-location "D:\My (x64) path"`

Comment: Use `powershell -noexit "Set-Location 'D:\My (x64) path'"`.

Comment: Messed around a bit with your answer and it seems as it was me not using single quotes that help the situation since I can use the alias cd instead of Set-Location in your answers. Is there any difference between single and double quotes that I have missed? If you add this as answers I'll mark my question as answer. Thanks  a bunch.

Comment: while i am not _certain_ of it, my understanding is that the filesystem provider uses some special chars as part of the wildcard search system. the reason the `-LiteralPath` parameters exist on some cmdlets is to allow one to disable that. so the best way to avoid your problem is to use the actual parameter names ... and to use `-LiteralPath` with `Set-Location`. [*grin*]

Comment: the real problem was that your quotes where wrong `"CD "` `"D:\My (x64) path"` `""`...  Double quotes close double quotes and singelquotes close single quotes. A path that contains a space needs quotes. `'D:\My (x64) path'` is the path and `"CD 'D:\My (x64) path' "` is a string containing a cmdlet and a path